App Store missing API declaration (for May 2024+)
I just uploaded an update to my app and received the following response from Apple:

Although submission for TestFlight review was successful, you may
want to correct the following issues in your next submission for
TestFlight review. Once you've corrected the issues, upload a new
binary to App Store Connect.
ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Runner”
file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the
following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults.
While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when
you upload a new app or app update, you must include a
NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to
provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For
more details about this policy, including a list of required reason
APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.
ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Runner”
file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the
following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace. While
no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you
upload a new app or app update, you must include a
NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to
provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For
more details about this policy, including a list of required reason
APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

I don't know much about the Apple environment outside of uploading my Flutter app via xcode. What do I need to do specifically? The links they provided didn't help.
My app uses Push notification via firebase, and this was set up with analytics. My app also imports data to the app via JSON API from my domain, and HTML data from another domain. The app also has web views (ring-fenced to only a handful of domains). The app also checks the connection state (has internet or not). There is no login or user area, and its a free app.
Everything is set up and runs correctly with Testflight.

Apple has changed some of its policy, so now they want you to have a Privacy Manifest file in the ios assets folder that will tell them how your app uses the platform apis. You are getting diskspace and user default warning because i think internally firebase use diskspace for peristence. So what you can do is update all the packages so that, package which uses platform apis will have the privacy file updated like in videoplayer,plus plugins,geolocator etc and what more you can do is to have you privacy manifest file added in the app with the diskspace and user default keys and their category.
You can get better idea if you check this thread:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/131940
Or in worst case you can add the above keys with minimum level of permission and try to submit it, but this is not recommended by flutter team, so i will also not recommend that

Thanks. I've updated my packages. I've checked and "use_frameworks!" is being used in cocoapods. I've created a PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy for the runner but I really don't know what to add. I've added NSPrivacyTracking TRUE and for NSPrivacyTrackingDomains I've added analytics.google.com but there is no documentation that mentions having to do this for Firebase analytics so I'm just making it up. Still no clearer on where the issue is coming from exactly :S

the api like disc,user default and time are very common and are used by many packages, and it is hard to know which package is using what, so it is better if you can ping flutter team on github or you can directly contact apple support for more info.
In the above thread #131940 pawlowskim addressed app_store_required_privacy_manifest_analyser which might be useful for you

An update to this. It's a pain, but it's done. The descriptions Apple gives are unnecessarily complicated and don't make sense for simpler apps. But I'll jump through crapple hoops to limp it to the line. As if I needed another reason to hate that "ecosystem"

If you have not getting this warning anymore. can you tell me your detail steps and can you add your PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy. I also encountered such prblm but have been waiting for flutter team response

It will be great if you can add it as answer with detail steps, like what problems you encountered, what was causing prblm and how you solved it. This answer will be very helpful for other flutter devs like us.
